# Material Design widgets for pre-lollipop

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm a bit weak in material design and styling.

First, My application's widgets are material on lollipop BUT on pre-lollipop it has another theme like holo or something. How should i implement Material Design for all API's?

Second, How can i get a list of v7 widgets like android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat ?

Comment: Some code require values-v11,17,21 is values of style for appropriate api version

Comment: @Ali Akhgar see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First question Answer :

Here is guideline how to support `Material Design for Pre Lolli Pop device`.

Visit this and read it :  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

#### Second question Answer :

Visit this link here you get all the `v7 widget` like you mention  `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat`.

Link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/package-summary.html

#### Third question Answer :

You use the `values-v11` and `values-v14` and and `values-v21` folders in order to set up values (`strings`, `dimens`, `styles`, etc) for different android versions. For example, `values-v11` targets android 11 and up. And you use the other two to target specific screen resolutions, and in the 2 case, a specific orientation as well.

Comment: thanks! is there any specific thing in v11 or v17 that we should adjust?
im making apps with only values and working fine! why is that so?

Comment: @AliAkhgar glad to help you.